# How to express "off-season" for « le rougissement des feuilles »?

Tags: expressions

In Japan, especially in Kyôto where I live, people enjoy *Kôyô*, « le rougissement des feuilles », in the autumn. Last weekend, while I was personally guiding a French speaker in town, I didn’t know how to idiomatically express the idea of:

> "Kôyô is now a little **off-season**, a few weeks **past their peak**".

The term « en basse saison » would apply to tourist resorts, but what about describing the concept of Kôyô (or for that matter, fruits, vegetables, and fishes) being off-season?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectivement la *basse* saison s'applique au domaine touristique (et s'oppose à *haute* et *moyenne* saison). Ces termes ne s'appliquent pas seulement aux stations touristiques mais à tout ce qui touche au tourisme, transports y compris.

Dans le domaine agricole on parle de *début de saison*, de *pleine saison* (ou juste de *saison*),  de *fin de saison* et de *hors saison* (ou *hors de saison*).

> C'est la pleine saison des huîtres en ce moment, il faut en profiter
>
> C'est la fin de la saison/ ce n'est plus la saison des [cox](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox%27s_Orange_Pippin), elles s'abîment vite.
>
> Les fraises sont hors saison chez nous, à cette époque tu ne trouveras que des fruits qui ont beaucoup voyagé et sans goût.

Un terme plus technique pour parler de *hors saison* est *contre saison*. Mais le terme est plutôt employé pour désigner des cultures effectuées en dehors de la période normale.

> [La consommation de fruits et légumes de contre-saison induit des gaspillages énergétiques et des émissions de gaz à effet de serre](http://www.adequations.org/spip.php?rubrique184).

Pour en revenir à ta question je dirais :

> La saison du *kōyō* tire à sa fin, les couleurs ne sont plus aussi resplendissantes/magnifiques.

Et en mars tu pourras dire :

> Ce n'est plus/pas la saison du *kōyō*, par contre c'est la pleine saison du *hanami* et je vais vous amener voir la beauté des cerisiers en fleurs.

Comment: Everything essentially centres round the word "saison", but the accurate expressions are quite varied, I see, depending on the thing being discussed. Au fait, il se trouve que je viens juste de manger des huîtres fraîches ce soir. Merci. :)